# How to open the native calendar app of the device in phonegap (cordova)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the Phonegap's calendar plugin "EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin" to access and create calendar events. But is there a plugin that opens the devices native calendar App.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plugin that executes this code

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"calshow://";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

Or you can try with existing plugins, like inappBrowser or [launchMyApp](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp) using `calshow://` as url

Comment: Kindly tell me the code to open the calendar through inappBrowser. I tried the below code but it didn't work.                                                                                              window.open('calshow://', '_system');

Answer (score 1):

The plugin `"EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin"` can also open the native calendar:

```
window.plugins.calendar.openCalendar();
```